# Reducing produced Yocto image size by removing python modules

Tags: yocto

So at the moment in my yocto build I have many python packages that are taking up alot of space that I dont need.

If I take an example, tkinter, I can't see why this is being added.
Looking at the toaster log, it has a reverse dependency for python3-modules and a dependency on python3-core

Python3-modules adds so many packages I dont need.

I actually just want to run django
Is there a way to remove these packages that I dont need? Seems strange that poky would add them when there are nothing using them.

Comment: Python3-modules is kind 'all others'. You can modify the manifest and remove those you do not need. The key is over here: http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python3/python3-manifest.json

Comment: Amazing thanks! I searched so much I don’t know how I missed it!

Comment: @vermaete any idea on best practices to remove? It says do not edit the manifest directly and doesn't say how to remove packages.

Comment: Well, you will void the warranty with changing the file :-).  Here you could remove python packages from python3-modules to get you image smaller (https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python3/python3-manifest.json#n760).  And regenerate the manifest file (https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python3/python3-manifest.json#n28).  But, again, this is quite a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vermaete said, removing from https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python3/python3-manifest.json#n760 indeed removes the packages.
Its a terrible way of doing it as you dont really want to modify anything in poky but it seems thats the only way

Comment: Another thing could be, if your filesystem is read-only, to remove the *.py files in /lib/... Check these slides of Scott Murray https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://elinux.org/images/8/8f/Poky-tiny_and_Beyond.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjd7PSl08fqAhXJ16QKHfvUAuwQFjADegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw2e_vtOujcpRGbUxNUSxPH3

Comment: Isn't there really no better way than do this in posprocess?     rm -rf ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/usr/lib/python3.9
    rm -rf ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/usr/include/python3.9